# How to get bytes of float in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I am looking for basically the exact same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21005845/3845439) but in Python.

How can I obtain the bytes in memory of a single-precision floating point variable in Python?  For instance if I have a variable `x = 0.65` I need to get some form of the list `[97, 102, 38, 63]`.

Answer (score 0):

**Bytes**:

```
x = 0.65
print(list(struct.pack("!f", x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import struct

ba = bytearray(struct.pack("f", 0.65))
print(ba[0], ba[1], ba[2], ba[3])
```